# MySQL - start hook

Tags: mysql

I have a process which depends on MySQL, and cannot work without it. Is there a way to hook into MySQL such that I can trigger this process to restart every time MySQL restarts? Right now, I am manually restarting the process (which crashes when MySQL goes down) to bring it back up.

Comment: What kind of process? Is it a service? Is it a client application? Webservice?

Comment: It's a service, to be specific, Celery (Python), which goes down when MySQL goes down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THere may be a way to "hook into mysql" to do this, but you don't need to. I'm going to assume you're running Linux or a UNIX variant, and that your instance of MySQL is listening on the default port (3306). Then the shell command:

netstat -an |grep 3306

will give you back a single line while the MySQL process is up, no output when it's down.

So write a Python script to run that command every T seconds and restart your process if it comes up empty, something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import commands


while 1:
    if not commands.getoutput("netstat -an |grep 3306"):
        # restart your process
    time.sleep(10)
```

That ought to do it.